# Python, recursions in range(a,b)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to finish 1 exercise but i cannot find a solution myself.
I get a number and function should use recursion to find a value:

```
if n == 1: return 1
elif n != 1: fun(n-1) + n
```

but i want to provide to my function 2 values, starting point and finishing point and my function finds all values in range(starting point, finishing point).

Comment: What do you mean by "all values". Do you mean the sum?

Comment: You're missing the `return` statement in the `elif` statement.

Comment: please show your function and complete code as well as input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function with two parameters. One of them gets idecremented when you make the recursive call, the other is kept the same:

```
def sumRange(start, end):
    if start > end:
        return None # or could signal an error
    elif start == end:
        return start
    else:
        return sumRange(start, end-1) + end
```

Don't forget that when you make the recursive call, you have to return the result.

Comment: You should have `if start>end` and not start<end